# ios Simulator - display os on top left quarter of the screen

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

The iOS Simulator displays its content only within the top left quarter of the screen instead of the full screen. As if the display was scaled to 25% inside the ios simulator window. The remaining 3/4 are black.
I played with scaling, reseting content, rebooting, killing the simulator, rebooting the mac... Still that strange behavior. But not on all devices.
I need to take some screenshots for the app store so if anyone knows what the problem is thank you in advance.
I'm on xcode 6.4

François

Comment: Are you seeing this just in your application, or does SpringBoard behave the same way?  You can hit cmd-shift-h to press the Home button to goto SpringBoard.  What happens when you take a screenshot from the file menu?  What types of displays do you have on your mac (retina, nonretina)?  What scale setting is the device at?  What is the device type?

Comment: SpringBoard behaves the same way. If I take a screenshot it shows the same problem. My screen is non-retina. It used to work (and still work with some devices of the simulator). The problem remains whatever the scale I pick.

Comment: Ok, please file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com and include as much information as possible.  Please also try the latest Xcode 7 beta to see if the issue reproduces in the newest version as well.